# How to store results in a variable? After running the code in the R Console

Tags: r

I was running the below code. The data was too high, and I forget to store the results in a variable.

```
wdbc <- read.csv("data.csv")

model <- lm(wdbc$reference~.,data = wdbc)

ols_coll_diag(model). #### The problem is here. I got the results in the console but I do not store them. It takes me a long time to run #####
```

***Is there a way to store the results without running the code again?***

Comment: Try `.Last.value`.

Comment: It gives me NULL

Comment: Did you run any other commands after `ols_coll_diag`?

Comment: Yes. I think so. But the results of 'ols_coll_diag' are still in the Console.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Unless you sink-ed the results, I don't think so.

Comment: You could copy the output from the console and paste it into a vector or data.frame. Several functions do have a `"clipboard"` support. But you mostlikely have to bring your output into a special form again. I recommend this only if your output is lost otherwise.